# How to pass a checkbox array from form to results page

Tags: javascript, jquery, detection, checkbox, combinations

Im trying to build a page that will allow a user to select a maximum of 8 out of 20 checkboxes, in a specific order, on a single form.

Im trying to make a page that will only be viewable if the right sequence of checkboxes are clicked, a neat way to let only those who have the checkbox sequence in on a certain part of my website.

What I need to know is, once they select the checkboxes, **how can I not only pass it on to a test page to view the data, but also, how to pass the data showing the exact sequence of how the checkboxes were checked**.

Example: The check boxes are numbered one from twenty. If they select checkbox1,checkbox4,checkbox2,checkbox7,etc, Id like the data to be passed on in the exact order checked, 1,4,2,7,etc

So far, I have have the form done, Id like to know what I need to add to the javascript in order to pass the variables on exactly as checked.

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

//initial checkCount of zero 
var checkCount=0

//maximum number of allowed checked boxes 
var maxChecks=3

function setChecks(obj){ 
//increment/decrement checkCount 
if(obj.checked){ 
checkCount=checkCount+1 
}else{ 
checkCount=checkCount-1 
}

//if they checked a 4th box, uncheck the box, then decrement checkcount and pop alert 
if (checkCount>maxChecks){ 
obj.checked=false 
checkCount=checkCount-1 
alert('you may only choose up to '+maxChecks+' options') 
}

}

//--> 
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var array = []; 
    $('input[name="checkbox"]').click(function () { 
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) { 
            // Add the new element if checked: 
            array.push($(this).attr('value')); 
        } 
        else { 
            // Remove the element if unchecked: 
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
                if (array[i] == $(this).attr('value')) { 
                    array.splice(i, 1); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        // Clear all labels: 
        $("label").each(function (i, elem) { 
            $(elem).html(""); 
        }); 
        // Check the array and update labels. 
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            if (i == 0) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("1"); 
            } 
            if (i == 1) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("2"); 
            }
            if (i == 2) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("3"); 
            } 
            if (i == 3) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("4"); 
            } 
            if (i == 4) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("5"); 
            } 
            if (i == 5) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("6"); 
            } 
            if (i == 6) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("7"); 
            } 
            if (i == 7) { 
                $("#" + array[i].toUpperCase()).html("8"); 
            }  
        } 
    }); 
});
//-->
</script>
```

Here is an example of the input fields:

```
    <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><label id="1"></label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="setChecks(this)"/></td>
    <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><label id="2"></label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="setChecks(this)"/></td>
    <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><label id="3"></label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="setChecks(this)"/></td>
    <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><label id="4"></label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="setChecks(this)"/></td>
    <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><label id="5"></label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="setChecks(this)"/></td>

and so on up to 20
```

I am a noobie, and I pieced together what I have so far, from various sources.

I am having trouble understanding how to grab the array data from the second snippet of javascript, and passing it along to a php page I need to create that will echo it in order to test to see if it is indeed passing along the variables in the exact order they were clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830961/javascript-checkbox-selection-order/3831467#3831467) that asks for a way to detect the order of selected checkboxes.

[Full code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuTYg/1/)

Select/Unselect the checkbox then click the textarea to see your array.

What I did there is simply add new element on the array when user select a checkbox. If he deselect it will find the index by its value and remove from the array.

Then you can check the length using `arrayName.length`, if it matches your condition then you can submit.

Comment: yeah, thats where i got the original snippet of code, I need a little more of a explaination, and I didnt want to take over that persons thread.

How exactly do i go about checking the array length, I couldnt quite grasp what was being said in that post.

Comment: I was actually looking at your code too, am I correct that I would nee to add your code as a whole? I couldnt tell if it was a mod of first answer, or if I need to add it entirely

Comment: it works really cool at jsfiddle, but the code I have works perfect esp for changing a checkbox mid selection. its just a lack of knowledge on my part of not know how to pass the variables.

Can you help me modify what I already have to parse to a test page, like your test page? your test page really rocks, didnt even think of that.

I feel like Im just missing one thing, and that grabbing the data from the second bit of javascript

Comment: The code you supplied is close, but im noticeing a lot of nulls if I deselect anything

Comment: You can't rely on the index being sequential. Use `for (var x in Xs)` syntax.

Comment: here is a updated version at js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4DZvn/3/

so everyone can see where I am at, and what direction Im going for

Comment: Actually I think I got it, I borrowed some of your code. Im gonna test it some more, as of right now it works pretty good

Comment: It is working so awesome, Ive got both the text area, and test length button working with my original code. Now Im just gonna look over everything to see how I can pass the variables along, hopefully I can figure it out. If someone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just push the IDs of the checkboxes onto an Array, then convert that to a string and post it back. Array[0] will be the first, etc. If Array.length > 7, disable the other checkboxes that are *not* in the array. That should be simple enough.

Comment: That sounds pretty cool, but it may be too complicated for me to get it. I appreciate it