# Storing checkbox values in order that they are clicked in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form that has 4 checkboxes and I want to be able to save the clicked checkboxes in the database but in the order, they are clicked. So for example, if I click the checkboxes in the order, 1, 3, 4, 2, it should save in the db in that order. At the moment, it just saved it in the default order despite me doing a selection in a different order. Is there any way to accomplish this?

My form:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
// Store the submitted data sent
// via POST method, stored 
// Temporarily in $_POST structure.
$_SESSION['system_battery_runout']
    = $_POST['system_battery_runout'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Rank form</title>
</head>
<body>  
        <div class="div2">
        <h1>Which Appliances Do You Use The Most?</h1>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">    
     <br />
<input  type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="Fridge" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> Fridge</label><br />
<input  type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="Stove" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> Stove</label><br />
<input  type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="TV" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> TV</label><br />
<input  type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="Water Tank" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> Water Tank</label><br />
<br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="float: right;" >
        </form>
        </div>     
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Insert Page</title>
</head>
</center>

<body>
    <div class="div2">
        <?php

        // serverfullname => localhost
        // userfullname => root
        // password => empty
        // database fullname => staff
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "survey");
        // Check connection
        if ($conn === false) {
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $system_battery_runout = $_SESSION['system_battery_runout'];
        $rank_appliances = $_POST['rank_appliances'];
        $checkboxvalue = implode(",", $rank_appliances);


        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cus_survey( system_battery_runout,rank_appliances)  VALUES (?, ?)");
        $sql->bind_param('ss', $system_battery_runout, $checkboxvalue);

        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {
            echo "<h3>Your survey was captured successfully. Thank You!";
        } else {
            echo "<h3>Sorry, something went wrong</h3> ";
        }

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is form element named `system_battery_runout`? Where is the database schema? If you used ajax you could send individual requests when each is clicked or do you wish to submit the form once in conventional manner? Either way you need javascript

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius this is just one form, the `system_battery_runout` is just taken from a previous form. This form calls an insert.php, which just stores the session data in the db

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I would prefer to submit the form then the records get saved

Comment: create a hidden input and populate with javascript when a checkbox is clicked/checked

Comment: You need javascript to handle the operation. Here is the solution I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/60884815/14032355

Comment: How would I go about saving it in my db though?

Answer (score 0):

A new, hidden field, can be populated easily using Javascript and will yield the clicked order when the form is submitted.

```js
let tmp=[];
let hidden=document.querySelector('input[name="rank_sequence"]');

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="rank_appliances[]"]').forEach( input=>input.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  /* Add the clicked value if checked or remove if unchecked */
  if( this.checked )tmp.push( this.value );
  else{
    if( tmp.includes( this.value ) )tmp.splice( tmp.indexOf( this.value ), 1 );
  }
  //add to the hidden input value
  hidden.value=tmp.join(',');
  console.info(hidden.value);
}));
```

```html
<div class="div2">
  <h1>Which Appliances Do You Use The Most?</h1>
  <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="Fridge" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> Fridge</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="Stove" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> Stove</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="TV" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> TV</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" style="height:20px; width:20px;" name="rank_appliances[]" value="Water Tank" /><label style="font-size: 20px;"> Water Tank</label><br />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="float: right;">
    <input type='hidden' name='rank_sequence' />
  </form>
</div>
```

Perhaps to process the new input element you could do the following (thoough untested)

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
    $_SESSION['system_battery_runout'],
    $_POST['rank_sequence']
)){

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "survey");
    $stmt=$conn->prepare('insert into `cus_survey` ( `system_battery_runout`, `rank_appliances` ) values (?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_SESSION['system_battery_runout'], $_POST['rank_sequence'] );
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $msg=( $stmt->affected_rows==1 ) ? 'Your survey was captured successfully. Thank You!' : 'Sorry, something went wrong';
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    printf('<h3>%s</h3>',$msg);
    
}
```

Comment: it still stores in the default order, any idea why?

Comment: The new field is called `rank_sequence` - it is that you need to process in PHP to add to the db. But you have not shown the PHP processing side so that is a mystery to all but you

Comment: I have updated the question to include the insert PHP script

Comment: you are not processing that hidden input value though

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm a novice with PHP, I apologize

Comment: Your `insert` statement is incorrect - it is missing a brace missing before the column names

Comment: oh yes, my error, but even corrected(also done in the question), it does not add. How would I be able process this new field?

Comment: see the amended answer above?!

Comment: That one gave me a `bind_param` error, any idea why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241060/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-jamesdayley1996).